# QAF | Scenario needs to skip if dependent scenario gets fail

Tags: qaf

Team,
Problem statement: Scenario2 should skip if dependent scenario1 gets fail. Need some support to fix this issue.
Reference: I took reference from below link [Skip Dependent scenario issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70758542/qaf-if-dependent-scenario-fails-running-scenario-should-skip)
Issue: End up with error after added **@dependsOnMethods:['scenario1']**

```
**Caused by: org.testng.TestNGException: 
Method "scenarios.suite1.feature.scenario2()[pri:2, instance:com.qmetry.qaf.automation.step.client.Scenario@2]" depends on nonexistent method "scenario1"**
```

Example Feature file:

````
```Feature: Google Search

@priority:1`enter code here`
Scenario: Scenario1
Given COMMENT: "SC1"
And Call negative step

@priority:2 @dependsOnMethods:['scenario1']
Scenario: Scenario2
Given COMMENT: "SC2" ```

    
**I used same listener from the above link**
````

public class DependecyListener implements ITestListener {

````
@Override
public void onTestStart(ITestResult result) {
ITestNGMethod method = result.getMethod();
String[] methodsDependedUpon = method.getMethodsDependedUpon();
if (method.isTest() && null != methodsDependedUpon && methodsDependedUpon.length > 0) {
List<String> methodsDependedUponLst = Arrays.asList(methodsDependedUpon);
IResultMap failedTests = result.getTestContext().getFailedTests();
List<ITestResult> falildMethodsDependedUpon = failedTests.getAllResults().stream()
.filter(t -> methodsDependedUponLst.contains(t.getName())).collect(Collectors.toList());
if(!falildMethodsDependedUpon.isEmpty()) {
throw new SkipException("Skipped because of dependency failure!");
}
}

} 


StepLibrary.Java

    ```@QAFTestStep(description = "Call negative step")
        public static void iCallNegativeStep() {
        System.out.println("Enter into Neg");
        Assert.assertEquals(true, false,"Called Negative step" );
            
        }```
````

Console Log:

```
-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------
Running TestSuite
log4j:WARN No such property [follow] in org.apache.log4j.FileAppender.
Added "QAFMethodSelector"
[ConfigurationManager] - ISFW build info: {qaf-Type=core, qaf-Revision=0b, qaf-Build-Time=24-Oct-2021 19:53:30, qaf-Version=3.1}
[ConfigurationManager] - Resource dir: D:\Temp\DelDepIssue\qaf-blank-project-maven-master\resources. Found property files to load: 6
[ConfigurationManager] - Resource dir: D:\Temp\DelDepIssue\qaf-blank-project-maven-master\resources. Found property files to load: 0
include groups []
 exclude groups: [] Scanarios location:  
org.apache.maven.surefire.util.SurefireReflectionException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException; nested exception is java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException: null
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:78)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodWithArray(ReflectionUtils.java:164)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory$ProviderProxy.invoke(ProviderFactory.java:110)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireStarter.invokeProvider(SurefireStarter.java:172)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireStarter.runSuitesInProcessWhenForked(SurefireStarter.java:104)
    **at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:70)
Caused by: org.testng.TestNGException: 
Method "scenarios.suite1.feature.Scenario2()[pri:2, instance:com.qmetry.qaf.automation.step.client.Scenario@2]" depends on nonexistent method "scenario1"**
    at org.testng.DependencyMap.getMethodDependingOn(DependencyMap.java:65)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.createDynamicGraph(TestRunner.java:1041)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:723)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:610)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:387)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:382)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:340)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:289)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1293)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1218)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1133)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1104)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGExecutor.run(TestNGExecutor.java:122)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGXmlTestSuite.execute(TestNGXmlTestSuite.java:92)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGProvider.invoke(TestNGProvider.java:101)
     9 more
Preparing For Shut Down...
[ResultUpdator] - Using QAF Json Reporter

Results :

Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  6.142 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2022-03-08T00:09:40+05:30
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 0):

While specifying dependency, method name value need to be **exact** same including upper/lower case, it is **case sensitive**. In your case  when providing method name in `dependsOnMethods` you didn't provided name in the same case. For instance, method name is `Scenario1` and in `dependsOnMethods` it is provided `scenario1`, if you observer it is not equal considering case sensitivity. That's why it complains that depends on nonexistent method `scenario1`. You can correct as sample below:

```
Scenario: Scenario1
Given COMMENT: "SC1"
And Call negative step

@priority:2 @dependsOnMethods:['Scenario1'] 
Scenario: Scenario2
```